# Improving encoding cycle

Tags: c#, foreach

I have this object: `Dictionary<byte, BitArray>()`

It's filled with values from a huffman tree. To encode each byte of the stream to the huffman binary value I do:

```
// Bytes are the bytes to be encoded, encoded is the output string
foreach (byte c in Bytes)
{
    encoded += _translationTable[c].ToBitsString();
}
```

This is the extension method:

```
//Converts the bitarray in a binary string
public static string ToBitsString(this BitArray bitArr)
{
    string retStr = string.Empty;

    foreach (bool bit in bitArr)
    {
        retStr += (bit) ? "1" : "0";
    }

    return retStr;
}
```

It takes nearly 3 seconds to encode 64kb of data, is there a way to achieve this result in a faster way?

Comment: What is `ToBitsString`?

Comment: Sorry I messed things up, I edited my question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're performing string concatenation in a loop. That's a [very inefficient way of building a new string](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html). I suspect you want:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte c in Bytes)
{
    builder.Append(_translationTable[c].ToBitsString());
}
var encoded = builder.ToString();
```

Now that we can see what `ToBitsString` does, it's easy to rewrite it to accept a `StringBuilder` to append to:

```
public static void AppendBitsTo(this BitArray bitArray, StringBuilder builder)
{
    foreach (bool bit in bitArray)
    {
        builder.Append(bit ? "1" : "0");
    }
}
```

Then the body of the loop would be:

```
_translationTable[c].AppendBitsTo(builder);
```

Comment: I forgot to post a piece of my program :D please have a look!

Comment: @Phate01: Right, so you've got string concatenation there *as well*... (I've edited my answer accordingly.)

Comment: I haven't tested it but I'm guessing that the problem is a matter of iterations number. On average a BitArray is 10 bits long for 64kb, so the program is doing 655360 iterations. I'm gonna test this solution